# "This version of SLF4J requires log4j version 1.2.12" warning with log4j 1.2.17

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, log4j, slf4j

I have a Java Maven project whose dependencies include `slf4j` and its `log4j adapter`.
I manage the versions of `log4j`, `slf4j-log4j12` and `slf4j-api` to its newest versions according to http://mvnrepository.com and especially the `log4j` version of 1.2.17 is well over 1.2.12 but I still get the error

```
SLF4J: This version of SLF4J requires log4j version 1.2.12 or later. 
    See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4j_version
```

which is totally unclear to me.

My Maven dependency management looks like this:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

How can I get rid of the warning?

P.S.: I also get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()`.

P.P.S.: Because of your comments I remembered that the program has a "lib" folder which is not included in the classpath by Maven but by Eclipse itself so the conflicting dependencies must lie there. Sorry, I totally forgot that I guess that's my fault for mixing Maven with a lib folder. I guess I must try to convert as much of the libraries to maven dependencies.
The strange thing though is just that even if I edit "Order and Export" to put the Maven dependencies at the top, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Try right clicking on the project and updating the project dependencies? Alternatively, try running `mvn dependency:tree` in command line to make sure that you are not using an older version being pulled in from elsewhere.

Comment: I looked at the dependency tree in Eclipse and it shows that all versions are managed to the ones I specified.

Comment: Does the issue occurs when running code in your IDE or only once deployed?

Comment: @Olivier.Roger I just noticed that the problem doesn't appear when I run it from the command line with "mvn test" but only in Eclipse. But the whole program doesn't work with maven because it has a library folder that is included in the Eclipse classpath.

Comment: I was asking because some App server, such as JBoss provide an old version of Log4J which can cause issues. So this is a classloader problem, maven built it correctly but is missing for dependencies. Could you try to provide the missing dependencies to maven?  Otherwise I suggest you look in the Eclipse specific dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! Converting the libraries to maven system dependencies (where there was no appropriate existing online dependency with the right version) did the trick, the warning and error are now gone.

Answer (score 6):

`StaticLoggerBinder` code in slf4j-log4j12 which gets loaded very early on performs a check to determine whether the `TRACE` level is available in log4j. Here is the code:

```
private StaticLoggerBinder() {
  loggerFactory = new Log4jLoggerFactory();
  try {
    Level level = Level.TRACE;
  } catch (NoSuchFieldError nsfe) {
    Util.report("This version of SLF4J requires log4j version 1.2.12 or later."+
                " See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4j_version");
  }
}
```

It seems pretty airtight to me.

It may be that some other dependency is pulling in or actually embeds an earlier version of log4j. Some **-standalone.jar* files are known to do that.

Check your class path at deployment time. Are you deploying in an app server? Is an older version of log4j on the server class path? In a java endorsed path?

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `<dependency>` outside the `<dependencyManagement>` as the following: -

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please see [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism: Dependency Management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) for further information.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Defining dependencies in the <dependencyManagement> is a good  practice but not mandatory. Moreover, it seems to me that it bears little or no relation to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Changing comment to answer, since it appeared to solve the issue.

> This is a classloader problem, maven built it correctly but is missing
>   for dependencies. Could you try to provide the missing dependencies to
>   maven? Otherwise I suggest you look in the Eclipse specific
>   dependencies.